# Fedora add Windows to grub

Tags: windows, fedora, grub, efi

I used to have Windows + Linux Mint in dualboot, but now I decided to install Fedora instead of Mint. I have Windows installed for about a month and now I finally have the time to Install fedora. However, the Windows 10 does not appear in grub.

What I already tried:

- grub-customizer. But it can't find Windows
- Adding custom entry in etc/grub.d/40_custom as said here https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/ques...
  But it didn't help.

Output of grzb2-mkconfig

```
[ajezek@localhost ~]$ sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
[sudo] password for ajezek: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-da325ed6b7fc41dab3e1b04fa22ea0b4
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-da325ed6b7fc41dab3e1b04fa22ea0b4.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-4.8.6-300.fc25.x86_64.img
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-0-rescue-da325ed6b7fc41dab3e1b04fa22ea0b4
Found initrd image: /boot/initramfs-0-rescue-da325ed6b7fc41dab3e1b04fa22ea0b4.img
done
```

fdisk: (both Windows and Fedora installed on sdb (240GB SSD), sda is 1TB HDD with data only and some Lenovo recovery partition)

```
[ajezek@localhost ~]$ sudo fdisk -l
[sudo] password for ajezek: 
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D1425B80-9CC2-4A00-9762-65C4E15D3D92

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     923647     921600   450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda3   310075392 1921404927 1611329536 768.4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  1921404928 1953523711   32118784  15.3G Windows recovery environment


Disk /dev/sdb: 223.6 GiB, 240057409536 bytes, 468862128 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 503D3D3C-C8C7-4771-84A7-61335D527168

Device         Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1       2048     34815     32768   16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sdb2     204800 419635199 419430400  200G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb3      34816    204799    169984   83M EFI System
/dev/sdb4  419635200 461578239  41943040   20G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb5  461578240 467869695   6291456    3G Linux swap
```

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Fedora was installed on sdb4 with EFI partition on sdb3. Windows is installed on sdb2.

GParted:

[image]

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

First, be sure that you've disabled both Fast Startup and Hibernate in Windows, as described here:

- [Disable Fast Startup](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html)
- [Disable Hibernate](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2859-hibernate-enable-disable-windows-10-a.html)

If either of these features is active, it can leave the [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) in an inconsistent state, which can lead to `os-prober` failing to detect Windows.

Second, if the preceding doesn't help, you might want to give my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) a try. It sometimes does a better job than GRUB at this task. You can try it from a USB flash drive or CD-R if you like, and then install it to your hard disk only if it works as expected. Note, however, that my USB flash drive and CD-R images don't support Secure Boot, so if Secure Boot is active you'll need to either temporarily disable it or jump through some hoops to add Secure Boot support to those images. I provide an RPM version of rEFInd, so installation is easy; but if you want to boot with Secure Boot active, you'll need to add the rEFInd key to your MOK list. See the [rEFInd Secure Boot documentation](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/secureboot.html) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You need os-prober to detect other systems :

> sudo dnf install os-prober

if installed you should re-run grub2-mkconfig.

Comment: `os-prober` is installed by default in Fedora 25, and it appears to be a dependency of `grub2`, so it seems unlikely that it would be accidentally deleted. Still, you're right that it's worth double-checking its presence.